# Show that $x=-ln(x)$,$x\in ]0,+\infty[$ has a unique solution.

Tags: numerical-methods, roots, fixed-points

Show that $x=-ln(x)$,$x\in ]0,+\infty[$ has a unique solution.
Show that the iterative method $x_{n+1}=-ln(x_n)$ diverge giving $x_0 >0$
And purpose a method of approximating the solution.

My try:

Let $f(x)=x+ln(x)$ then  $f'(x)=1+\frac 1x >0$ Hence  $f$ is an increasing function and let $0<a<1$ and $b\geq 1$ so $f(a)f(b)<0$ by MVT we deduce there exists a unique solution on $]0,+\infty[$.
The second question let $g(x)=-ln(x)$ then $g'(x)=-\frac 1x$ Hence $|g'(x)|>0$ that is $g$ is not a contaction.
I suggest the Newton-Raphson method s.t $x_0>0,\quad x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}.$
Is this correct?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @StiftungWarentest this is an exercise but is it correct what i did ?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're doing on the first part. I assume you want to apply the Intermediate Value Theorem, for that you would need to show, that $f$ is continuous and that $\exists a,b\in(0,\infty)$ s.t. $f(a)\leq 0 \leq f(b)$. Uniqueness then follows from strict monotonicity

Comment: @geetha290krm So what did you show from that  ?

Comment: It answers your question.

Comment: @geetha290krm that exactly what i did

Comment: Newton_Raphson is not guaranteed to converge. So just saying "use it" is not sufficient (in my opinion). I suggest adding an argument that it will converge in this case. For an example of it not converging, consider $h(x) = x-1$ for $x \le -1, h(x) = x+1$ for $x \ge 1$, and connect them with an S-shape passing through the origin. If the starting value has $|x| \ge 1$, Newton-Raphson will just lead to $1, -1, 1, -1, \ldots$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair thank you so much. so what about Regular falsi or secant method ?

Comment: Neither is guaranteed to converge, either. For guaranteed convergence, you can use Bisection, but for practical purposes, it is slow.